# Keep identifying features when using map() to "spread_predictions" in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, model, purrr

I am trying to build a linear model, and then make predictions with new data based on that linear model. The following chunk of code takes a given set of data (data1), and produces 20 models based on the fact that when I group by ID and plot, there are 20 groups:

```
modelobject <- data_1 %>% 
  group_by(ID, plot) %>% 
  do(model = lm(air_temp ~ water_temp, data = .)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Now that the model is designed, I want to use the map() function to make predictions across a new set of data (data_2) for each of those models:

```
modelled_values <- map(modelobject$model, ~ spread_predictions(data = data_2, models = .x))
```

This works great, except for the fact that the subsequent object modelled_values doesn't have the identifying features of the original models (i.e. their given ID and plot) as can be seen in the following output for the Value column (it produces 11 columns, none of which are identifying features):

```
Value
List of length 20
A data.frame with 52606 rows and 11 columns
....
```

I have ended up having to assume that they are just in the order I produced them in and manually label each model object with the following style of code:

```
modelled_values[[1]]$ID <- "ID1"
modelled_values[[2]]$ID <- "ID1"
modelled_values[[3]]$ID <- "ID2"
modelled_values[[4]]$ID <- "ID2"
...
```

Is there any way I can carry the identifying features of the original models over to these predicted data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
modelobject <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by(vs, am) %>% 
  do(model = lm(mpg ~ hp, data = .)) 
preds <- modelobject %>% 
  group_by(vs, am) %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  summarise(preds = list(predict(model, newdata=mtcars)))

preds
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
# # Groups:   vs, am [4]
#     vs    am preds     
# <dbl> <dbl> <list>    
# 1     0     0 <dbl [32]>
# 2     0     1 <dbl [32]>
# 3     1     0 <dbl [32]>
# 4     1     1 <dbl [32]>
```

In the code above, `preds` is now a tibble with a column called `preds` where each element is as vector of predictions from the model for the relevant `vs` and `am` values in the row.